# if i use array.size() for the "toIndex" of the subList, is it going to be inclusive?

Tags: recursion, arraylist, sublist

i am using sublist for the first time, and thought if i put the size of my array as the toIndex, it is going to be inclusive. but when printing the results it is not including the last element of the arraylist. i am trying to sum the elements of the arrayList using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

In Java `subList(int x, int y)` will return list from x element to y-1 element.
For list = [0, 1, 2, 3], `list.subList(1, 3)` will return [1, 2].

It will work for correctly for your function.
For example:

```
Integer count(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.size() == 1) return list.get(0);
    int index = list.size() / 2;
    return count(list.subList(0, index)) +  count(list.subList(index, list.size()));
}
```

Comment: thanks! it was definitely helpful. for some reason the first element of the array was not printing. i did this and it solved the problem. but i still don't know what exactly happened. I'm just glad it worked!                  array.add(0, temp);
       System.out.printf("the recursive result:$ %.2f " ,count(array));

Comment: Please, add your code in question - it will be easier to troubleshoot.